# Modern.ie Virtual Machine : Purchasing perpetual/subscription for Virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, licensing, modern.ie

The T&C for the Modern.ie Virtual machine licence states

> 3. TIME-SENSITIVE  SOFTWARE.       You may use the software    for 90  days    after   it  is  downloaded  to  the 
>      licensed    computer.       The software    will    stop    running after   90  days    and you may not receive any other
>      notice.     You may not be  able    to  access  data    used    with    the software    when    it  stops   running.

We would like to perform cross-browser testing and we find modern.ie more reliable. Is there a way to purchase licence legally? I checked the [T & C page](https://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/virtualmachine_instructions_2014-01-21.pdf) and StackOverflow site and there is no reference or contact info on how to purchase perpetual/subscription licence.

Since many of our clients are using older versions of IE and forcing them to use Edge may not be an option, can Microsoft advice how to purchase legal perpetual/subscription based licences. Per policy, Our company cannot allow to extend trial-versions in our desktop.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Any legal key for windows that is still valid should work.